# How to get "returning id" using asyncpg(pgsql)

Tags: python, python-3.x, postgresql, asyncpg

Use asyncpg to execute the insert statement in Python, and use the returning id syntax to get the ID of each insert, but return the "INSERT 0 1"

Python 3.5

asyncpg (Using Connection Pool)

[image]

Comment: I don't see any `con.fetchone()` after `con.execute()`?

Comment: So i need use fetchval ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Connection.fetch()` (and its variants) can be used to return the results of any data-returning statement, including `INSERT ... RETURNING id` or `INSERT ... RETURNING *` if you need all columns.